# Unable to access ec2 instance with wordpress installed on it

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, amazon-ec2, https

Not sure if I am in a right forum. I have an EC2 instance(ec7-1-33-24-12.compute-1.amazonaws.com) and connected to my domain name(mydomain.com). I was getting a security error on top of the browser hence I tried to install SSL from https://letsencrypt.org/. Once I did that I was unable to access the web page with HTTP and https both. Was not loading page at all.

To resolve this:

> 1. I uninstalled all the letsencrypt.org SSL configurations/libraries and folders.

Still, I was not able to access my EC2 instance or domain from the browser.

To resolve I have to again:

> 1. Copies all the files from /var/www.html directory to another folder.
> 2. Uninstalled HTTPd deleted /var/www folder reinstalled https again
> 3. Did exactly the same from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html
> 4. Now again I am unable to access the apache server
> 5. When I copy the EC2 URL its coping with HTTPS and when I change the HTTPS I am able to see apache server details
> 6. My own domain is still down, not working at all
> 7. phpinfo.php page is not working, I am getting a static text from them. I have a current version of PHP with 7.2.

Please help how to resolve this issue, or I have to create a separate EC2 instance and backup all copied files to it.

Thanks!

Comment: What static text are you getting? It sound like your Apache conf file is maybe getting messed up.

Comment: I am getting `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: If that's the output you're seeing in your browser from hitting `phpinfo.php`, then it would seem that Apache is not correctly configured to deal with PHP files.

Comment: Initially, it was working fine but when I tried to add SSL certificate it got messed by. I deleted all the Apache configuration and reinstalled again.. still it's not working..